# Get Shortcut Recorder working in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, shortcut, hotkeys, recorder

Is there any way to have a Shortcut Recorder in Objective-C, where the user can choose the shortcut?

I tried `DDHotKey`, which worked for me, but with this library users can not choose the shortcut themselves.

Then I tried to implement the `Shortcut Recorder`, but there I can only work with Xcode 3 because of the ibplugin.

So is there any way to have something like this in Xcode 4 ? :[image]

**Mentioned Libraries:**

DDHotKey: [Here](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey)

Shortcut Recorder:[Here](https://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/)

Comment: jep just have a look at: https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBPlugins do not work in Xcode 4, as you've found out.  ([File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you want them back)  However, this does not prevent you from instantiating the control programmatically...

Comment: i instantiated the control programmatically now but how can i move on now ? i don't know how to get the entered key combo and how to react if this combo was pressed ?

Comment: because my application doesn't execute the keyComboDidChange method although i set the delegate

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible--take a look at [Jumpcut's source](https://github.com/snark/jumpcut). You might have to change the build settings to use LLVM compiler 3.0 for it to build in Xcode 4, but it's a pretty good example Shortcut Recorder implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is Shortcut Recorder patch I wrote to use user defined runtime attribute on xcode 4.

You don't need to use ibplugin but just editing NSTextField and its cell.

See [issue 58](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/issues/detail?id=58)